# Disable cache for ethersjs

Tags: ethers.js

I want to disable cache when suing ethersjs v6. Did not find any documentation related to that. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the provider options, you can pass a negative `cacheTimeout` which would disable caching ([source](https://github.com/sentioxyz/ethers.js/blob/0aecac3734bb063c7ea39332d9daa58cc8c36471/src.ts/providers/abstract-provider.ts#L538-L539)).

```typescript
const provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider(
  "https://rpc.url",
  undefined,
  {
    cacheTimeout: -1,
  }
);
```

Comment: I see that was added in 6.6.x, 2 weeks ago, was using older version. Thanks a lot!